# Sub String in C++

Tags: c++, string, substring

This is my C++ code.

```
int main(){
        string str("xxxxx     250 15");
        string data(str,10,13);

        cout<<data;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I need to get value "250 " from the above string. My total string size is 16. After running this program I got the below output.

250 15. 
But I gave index to get only "250 ". But I'm getting wrong answer. It give me a result until the end of the string. Why I'm getting the result "250 15" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`10,13` is wrong, you're not supposed to give it a range, but the start and number of characters - i.e. `10,3` - starting from character 10, give me 3 characters.

```
string data(str,10,3);
```